# Counting occurrences of integers in an array in Java

Tags: java, loops

Note: no mapping, no sorting

Here's my code:

```
public static void countArray(int[] n){
    int[] m = new int[n.length]; //50 elements of integers between values of 10 & 20
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n.length ; i++){
        m[i] = n[i]; //make a copy of array 'n'
        System.out.print(m[i]+" ");

    }System.out.println();

    for ( int j =0; j < n.length ; j++){
        count =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n.length ; i++){
            if (n[j]%m[i]==0 && n[j] == m[i])
                count++;
        }if ( n[j]%m[j] == 0)
        System.out.println(m[j] + " occurs = " + count);
    }   
}
```

So the problem is: I get repeating results like : "25 occurs = 5", on different lines.

What I think: the problem occurs because of `if ( n[j]%m[j] == 0)` 
so I tried `if ( n[j]%m[j+1] == 0)`. Another problem occurs since `m[j]` will be `m[50]` so it crashes but sort of give me the results that I want.

Result that I want: something like this: no repetitions and covers all the random integers on a set

```
17 occurs = 3
23 occurs = 2
19 occurs = 3
15 occurs = 2
12 occurs = 2
```

Comment: "*no mapping, no sorting*" You just ruled out the sensible solutions. Why can't you use these?

Comment: First, there is no one perfect answer.  Second, what is it you think n[j]%m[j] is doing for you?  You haven't commented your code so it's really difficult to follow the approach you're trying to take.

Comment: @Radiodef haven't learned those yet.
and CandiedOrange I think it's just checking itself, know what I mean?

Comment: So why don't you want to learn something new?

Comment: @Radiodef I do want to learn new things, however, I am doing this assignment based on what we have learned in class... I thought I mentioned it on my description.

Comment: No, you did not say exactly that. ; ) The problem is that it makes it difficult for us to answer. Answering the question as it is asked forces us to both do your homework for you and show you a less than ideal solution.

Comment: @Radiodef pretty sure I've much of the work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some adaptation your code should work :

```
public static void countArray(int[] n){
    boolean [] alreadyCounted = new boolean[n.length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length ; i++){
        int count = 0;
        if (alreadyCounted[i]) {
            // skip this one, already counted
            continue;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < n.length ; j++){
            if (n[i] == n[j]) {
                // mark as already counted
                alreadyCounted[j] = true;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(n[i] + " occurs = " + count);
    }   
}
```

You could definitely use the same logic with better code, I just tried to follow the original "coding style";

This is O(n^2) solution (read *"very slow"*). 
If you could use sorting, you could do it in O(n log(n)) - that is *fast*.
With mapping you could do it in O(n) - that is *blazingly fast*;

Comment: code works like charm. any suggestions in order for me to improve my coding?

Comment: To improve your coding you should first understand how the code in my answer works and then implement this logic they way you like. 
Also, I recommend to always write pseudo code before actual implementation.

Comment: how do i make the output go in an ascending order? i.e 10 occurs = 1, 11 occurs = 2, and so on ....

Comment: @ArcRanges you can't without using sorting.

Comment: I see. Anyways, is there anyway to ask another question here? I have a problem but on a different kind of method. I already asked two questions and that's my limit.

Comment: @ArcRanges Sure. Why don't you just post another question on SO ? or don't you have enough reputation for that ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :(sort the array and then count the occurence of element)

```
public static void countArray(int[] n) {
    int count = 0;
    int i, j, t;
    for (i = 0; i < n.length - 1; i++) // sort the array
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n.length; j++) {
            if (n[i] > n[j]) {
                t = n[i];
                n[i] = n[j];
                n[j] = t;
            }

        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n.length;)
    {
        for (j = i; j < n.length; j++) {
            if (n[i] == n[j])
            {
                count++;
            } else
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(n[i] + " occurs " + count);
        count = 0;
        i = j;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exploit the input limit you can lose the nested loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //6 elements of integers between values of 10 & 20
    int[] countMe = { 10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 15 };

    countArray(countMe);
}

/** Count integers between values of 10 & 20 (inclusive) */
public static void countArray(int[] input)
{
    final int LOWEST = 10;
    final int HIGHEST = 20;

    //Will allow indexes from 0 to 20 but only using 10 to 20
    int[] count = new int[HIGHEST + 1]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        //Complain properly if given bad input
        if (input[i] < LOWEST || HIGHEST < input[i])
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("All integers must be between " +
                    LOWEST + " and " + HIGHEST + ", inclusive");
        }

        //count
        int numberFound = input[i]; 
        count[numberFound] += 1;
    }

    for(int i = LOWEST; i <= HIGHEST; i++)
    {
        if (count[i] != 0) 
        {
            System.out.println(i + " occurs = " + count[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to zero out your array. Java will do that for you whenever you declare a `new int[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice, efficient way to do it, rather more efficiently than the other solutions posted here. This one runs in O(n) time, where the array is of length n. It assumes that you have some number `MAX_VAL`, representing the maximum value that you might find in your array, and that the minimum is 0. In your commenting you suggest that `MAX_VAL==20`.

```
public static void countOccurrences(int[] arr) {
    int[] counts = new int[MAX_VAL+1];
    //first we work out the count for each one
    for (int i: arr)
        counts[i]++;
    //now we print the results
    for (int i: arr)
        if (counts[i]>0) {
            System.out.println(i+" occurs "+counts[i]+" times");
            //now set this count to zero so we won't get duplicates
            counts[i]=0;
        }
}
```

It first loops through the array increasing the relevant counter each time it finds an element. Then it goes back through, and prints out the count for each one. But, crucially, each time it prints the count for an integer, it resets that one's count to 0, so that it won't get printed again.

If you don't like the `for (int i: arr)` style, this is exactly equivalent:

```
public static void countOccurrences(int[] arr) {
    int[] counts = new int[MAX_VAL+1];
    //first we work out the count for each one
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        counts[arr[i]]++;
    //now we print the results
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if (counts[arr[i]]>0) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+" occurs "+counts[arr[i]]+" times");
            //now set this count to zero so we won't get duplicates
            counts[arr[i]]=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However,we haven't learned (dataType : arrayName) so I think the first one is perfect.

Comment: You could replace your second loop with looping over counts[] and printing indices for nonzero items. Nice solution, however implementing simple mapping, which OP seems to not like to use.

Comment: @kiruwka does not like to use mapping for now since professor might deduct marks.

Comment: @kiruwka It rather depends on what "mapping" means. I'd taken it to mean that you can't use a Java `Map`. Also, looping over `counts[]` isn't as good because the complexity changes from `O(n)` to `O(n+MAX_VAL)`, which is strictly worse if `MAX_VAL` is bigger than `n`.

Comment: @ArcRanges I've added the equivalent with "normal" `for` loops. The first one is really bad: as is noted there, it's O(n^2), which is really slow. On a large array, you'd notice in a big way.

Comment: @chiastic-security Good point about last loop. As for effectiveness, your solution might be way too memory greedy if the input range constraints are not satisfied, worth mentioning that as well.

Comment: @chiastic-security  tried this code and it gave me repeated results   AND counts[arr[i]] is always =1.

Comment: @ArcRanges No, it works fine. I've just run it on `{1,3,11,3,14,1,10}` and it gave me correct results with no duplicates (both versions).